# Selenium: Element is not clickable. It's a button. I cannot resolve it

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Obligatory: New to `Selenium webdriver` and Python.

I am attempting to scrape cricket scores from this page
https://www.playhq.com/cricket-australia/org/saca-premier-cricket/senior-men-summer-202324/west-end-mens-2nd-grade/game-centre/7cb22178

It has all gone swimmingly for the data on-screen in the initial view.

When I try to click the **Glenelg 1st Innings** button to change the view, I get:

```
Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (316, -283)
```

I have tried using a variety of `xpaths`. This appears to be the best option

```
//*[@data-testid='period-tab-container']/button[2]
```

I am able to resolve the correct text from these `xpaths`.

I don't think it is related to implicit wait times. I'm using driver.implicitly_wait(5).

Everything else is present on this page.

Of course, I could be incorrect.

These score pages are dynamically created. Are they masking the button functionality somehow?

I have tried using the brute force path `//button[text()='Glenelg 1st Innings']`

It is clearly finding the element. I can read the text.

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    targetURL = "https://www.playhq.com/cricket-australia/org/saca-premier-cricket/senior-men-summer-202324/west-end-mens-2nd-grade/game-centre/7cb22178"


    driver.get(targetURL)
    title = driver.title
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    # lots of other code in here
    # is able to correctly resole page elements
    # removed for brevity

    other_innings_button = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,
        value="//*[@data-testid='period-tab-container']/button[2]")
    print(other_innings_button.text)
    other_innings_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of :

```
 other_innings_button.click()
```

you must use:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

other_innings_button.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: This works! Thank you so much. I would not have found this. It looks like more experience with Selenium Webdriver will be a good thing.